# How can I print out a form in a twig template file

Tags: theming, 8

I am looking to use bootstrap modal window to show a Drupal form, and the easiest way to do it seems to be to put the bootstrap html into a twig template file, however I have no idea how to render out the form inside this html.

Comment: use `{{ form }}`

Comment: Surely it's not this simple?

Comment: Yes, it's that simple - your question asked how to print the form in a template - the answer given by No Sssweat is 100% technically correct. The trick here is simple - ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did it, for anyone that needs this:

```
  $myform = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\[mymodule]\Form\[myformclass]');
  $build = [
    '#theme' => 'twigTheme'
    '#form' => $myform,
  ];
```

In twig:

```
{{ form }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain where to get the form class from and also what does {{ form }} refer to in the above code? Also where does the PHP go? Into the.theme file?

Comment: @JoeyDrupal based on your comment, sounds like you did not create this form your self. Is this for a form that comes with drupal?

Comment: You can get FORM class in your form it is like class EXAMPLEFORM extends EntityDisplayModeFormBase{, here EXAMPLEFORM is your form class name. and {{ form }} this you have to write in you twig file, which refers to $myform to render and print form in twig file. In D8 twig files there is no PHP in it like rendering form directly ,as it uses SYMPHONY.

Comment: why isn't it {{ myform }} ?

Comment: and I still don't understand where to find my form class sorry

Comment: This is a form created with YAML form or Contact form

Comment: What if I want to use more than one form in a twig file? How does that {{ form  }} correspond to whichever form I am calling. This is very confusing and I don't feel like it is being explained

Comment: And now my question has been voted down, talk about helping people to learn. Thanks very much

Comment: The variable is `form` because it was passed in the `#form` property of the render array. That's the convention Drupal uses. It could just as easily be `myForm` instead of or in addition to `form`

Comment: No I want to just render out a form in page.html.twig

Comment: It sounds like there are a lot of things about theming you don't understand here. Id advise reading the theming guide and then coming back to it